# What does the number 37 mean in Song of the Bandits?

Tags: song-of-the-bandit

Most of the military personnel seem to have the number 37 on their collars. What does this number mean? Where does it come from?

[image: number 37 on the collar of a soldier in the tv show Song of the Bandits]

Comment: Regiment number? That's what it would be if it were a French army uniform of the period anyway...

Answer (score 5):

These appear to be [Japanese Imperial Army uniforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_of_the_Imperial_Japanese_Army), circa 1920, and those would be regiment numbers. So it's regiment number 37

> [image]

You can see a museum example here.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>**45 Shiki-Gun-i uniform** (1911)</sup></sub>

---

The show seems to be quite [well researched](https://usacac.army.mil/sites/default/files/documents/carl/nafziger/939JXAA.pdf). The 75th was a cavalry regiment. The 37th was an infantry regiment.